# Concurrent firing event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to know why this code below is running wrong. I've a checkbox which fires a function called Uncheck. However if I click quickly, like 0.4s or less between each click I get it fails. My array has gotten duplicated values.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="uni2198" name="uni" value="2198" onclick="Uncheck('2198')">
```

**JS**

```
unidadesSelecionadas = {};
function Uncheck(id) {            
    var idSelect = '#uni' + id;

    if ($(idSelect).is(':checked')) {                   
        if ($.inArray(parseInt(id), unidadesSelecionadas) == -1) {
            unidadesSelecionadas.push(id);          
        }
    } else {
        unidadesSelecionadas.splice($.inArray(parseInt(id), unidadesSelecionadas), 1);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onchange instead of onclick and see:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="uni2198" name="uni" value="2198" onchange="Uncheck('2198')">
```